# flexible class name using python (py2neo Metaclasses used)

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2neo

Until now i have not found the answer to this question (more a general Python question than explicite for py2neo)
I want to be able to call py2neo classes flexible:

```
class foo1(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "bar"
    bar = Property()
    foobar = RelatedTo("foo1")
    foobar2 = RelatedTo("foo1")

class foo2(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "bar"
    bar = ""
    foobar = RelatedTo("foo2")
    foobar2 = RelatedTo("foo2")

def flexiblefoocreate(classname,newbar):
    #classname is "foo1" or "foo2"
    tempvar=classname()
    tempvar.bar=newbar

def flexiblefoobaradding(classname,startbar,foobarname,endbar)
    #classname is "foo1" or "foo2"
    #foobarname is "foobar" or "foobar2"
    startfoo=classname()
    startfoo.bar=startbar
    endfoo=classname()
    endfoo.bar=endbar
    startfoo.foobarname.add(endfoo)
```

How can I get this working?

background:
Later on easy adding/using of properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use metaclasses:

```
class Foo1(object):
    def d1(self):
        print(self, ".d1")


class Foo2(object):
    def d2(self):
        print(self, ".d2")


def make_class(base):
    return type(str(base), (base,), {})


MyExtraordinarilyNamedFoo1Class = make_class(Foo1)
MySimpleFoo2Class = make_class(Foo2)

foo1 = MyExtraordinarilyNamedFoo1Class()
foo2 = MySimpleFoo2Class()

foo1.d1()
foo1.new_attr = 1
print(foo1.new_attr)

foo2.d2()
foo2.new_attr = 2
print(foo2.new_attr)
```

Comment: thank you! Gonna fiddle around with that to fully understand the structure.

what is pass used for in this case?

and working with the .foobar and .foobar2 I should use getattribute? How can I create a new attribute out of a string?

Comment: @resc if you want to have dynamic properties, check prodict (https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict/)

Comment: when I try to use your code, it throws an syntax error, how can i use your make_class?

Comment: @resc I am pretty sure my code works, but I use python 3.6.3. I thing you are on python 2.x

Comment: i am on python 3.6.4 and if i want to run, the "," between the "(" ")" is too much.
And I do not see where u use base again, or is it a keyword i do not know? :)

Comment: @resc Try again

Comment: you are a genius! this is awesome :)

for people being interested: [link](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/)